# How to detect what class a parameter is from

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have two classes, Class A and Class B.  They can both call the same method in a controller. The method they call takes in a `CGPoint`.  Is there any way I can determine which class the argument came from?

I have tried using the following:

```
if ([point isKindOfClass:[_territoryPaths class]])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *territoryPaths = [_territoryPaths territoryPaths];
}

if ([piont class] == [_territoryPaths class])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *territoryPaths = [_territoryPaths territoryPaths];
}
```

`point` is the `CGPoint` that the method takes in.

Comment: Short of some really flaky tricks with the call stack (if even those are possible) you need to somehow pass the ID of the caller.

Comment: What is you goal here? This sounds like a bad design. But more needs to be know before a good solution can be offered.

Comment: (Note that a CGPoint is not an object, just a struct.  And it's usually passed directly vs by explicit pointer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to deal with this situation if you want to use this method in a class that is not ClassA or ClassB would be to modify your method so that it accepts a sender and do the isKindOfClass on the sender value.

For example:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)sender withPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]])
    {
        // Do class A stuff
    }
    else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[ClassB class]])
    {
        // Do class B stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Unknown class
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that, in general, using `isKindOfClass:` to switch between implementation behaviors is a sign of bad design.  A better solution would be to make `ClassA` and `ClassB` both implement the desired method or both classes inherent from an abstract superclass that stubs out the appropriate method.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Thanks for adding what I forgot to mention.